# regular expression to add quotes for string values

Tags: java, json, regex, string

I'm trying to add quotes for **string** values only in a file, for example:

```
String content = "ids:[\"123\"],name:null,Quantity:8d-1,number:123,name:\"hello\",id2:\"1234\"";
```

for `ids`, since it's an array, so it's fine. `name` is null so it's also good. `Quantity` needs quotes on its value, `number` is good as its value is digit. So the expected output is

```
"ids:[\"123\"],name:null,Quantity:"8d-1",number:123,name:\"hello\",id2:\"1234\"";
```

I wrote

```
content.replaceAll(":([^\"]+),", ":\"$1\",");
```

but which does not give me correct result. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: May we ask whence you obtained such malformed JSON?  The ideal place to fix this would be in the code which generates the original broken JSON, not downstream, after it has already been generated.

Comment: To add to @TimBiegeleisen's relevant question: Is the problem even solvable? I.e., what prevents a snippet like the following `…,Quantity:d8,1,number:123,…`? Is this to be considered `{"Quantity": "8d,1", "number": 123}`, or `{"Quantity": "8d", "1,number": 123}` or something else entirely?

Comment: good call! though this case won't happen in my files."8d,1" is the right solution

Comment: Thanks Tim, it's long story and I don't have permission to fix it from upstream

Comment: @user8142520  you may not have permission, but you don't have to clean up someone else's mess either. You hacking a "json" payload into shape is not a fix, it's a bandaid. NExt week there will be some other problem. Tim is right, fix the problem, which is somwhere at the source.

Comment: it also needs efforts because tones of files need to be backfilled

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to match strings that aren't entirely digits (actually more complicated)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63168039/how-to-match-strings-that-arent-entirely-digits-actually-more-complicated)

Comment: I believe the current Best Answer does what you want, since the question is based on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[user8142520](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8142520/user8142520),  the way you wrote it replaces everything that comes after `name`, and since the default is greedy, it gets the longest fit, which only happens at the comma after `number`.

The `name` field doesn't fit your regex because of double quotes in it.

I've assumed that the `Quantity` field can have any pattern that can be separated from the content of other fields.

So I add `y` before your regex, to limit the replacing scope on the `Quantity` field and I've replaced in the regex  `[^\"]` for `[^,]`, so the fit range doesn't invade other field.

```
content.replaceAll("y:([^,]+),", "y:\"$1\",")
```