# How to match strings that aren't entirely digits (actually more complicated)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this `RegExp`:

```
(?<=:)(?:(?!null|false|true)[\w\-])+(?=,)
```

The goal is to match all strings between `:` and `,` as long as they are not equal to `null`, `false`, or `true`.

Here is the test string:

```
ids:[\"123\"],name:null,value:false,prop:true,Quantity:8d-1,number:123,name:\"hello\",id2:\"1234\"
```

The matches are `8d-1` and `123`.

How do I exclude matches that are entirely numbers, like `123`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use assert what is on the right is not one of the alternatives followed by a comma without using the quantifier for the group.

Then match `[\w-]+` and assert a comma at the right.

```
(?<=:)(?!(?:null|false|true|\d+),)[\w-]+(?=,)
```

- `(?<=:)` Positive lookbehind, assert a `:` directly to the left
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not

  - `(?:null|false|true|\d+),` Match one of the alternatives followed by a comma
- `)` Close lookahead
- `[\w-]+` Match 1+ times a word char or hyphen
- `(?=,)` Assert a comma at the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L4ztEX/1)

```js
const regex = /(?<=:)(?!(?:null|false|true|\d+),)[\w-]+(?=,)/g;
const str = 'ids:["123"],name:null,value:false,prop:true,Quantity:8d-1,number:123,name:"hello",id2:"1234"';
console.log(str.match(regex));
```